# How to execute a sql file (with both DDL and DML statements separated by ;) stored in GCS against Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a file on Google Cloud Storage that contains a number of queries( Create table, truncate/delete table, insert, merge, select etc). I need to execute all statements in sequence as they appear in the file against bigquery. How do I do that?

Comment: If you are working with an account manager as part of Google Cloud, you can ask them to help you sign up for BigQuery's scripting alpha feature that was announced at Google Cloud Next. If not, keep an eye on BigQuery's release notes to get notified about the beta

Comment: Hi Elliott, Is this what you are referring to? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/bq/  Using a shell script will be an ok solution but I would like it to do it from dataflow or cloud function. Any idea?

Comment: No, that's not what I was referring to. You could consider using Cloud Composer to execute sequential queries.

Comment: I was really hoping to execute my sql code as is, without spending hours converting it to the liking of some other tool, considering, most other analytic db engines support it without much fanfare and out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, at this moment there is no way to achieve this. You might follow the procedure:

**1.** Separate your file in order to have instructions DDL [following the correct syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language) and running them.

**2.** Create a CSV and import the data into the bigQuery, [following the procedure](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#loading_data_from_a_local_data_source).

If your database is huge, you may want to do the import [using the API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#api_uploads).

Also, here the [documentation for DML Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax).